# How would I run a batch file remotely over sccm in interactive cmd (micro right click tools)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, psexec, sccm

On SCCM you can right click --> Micro right click tools and interactive command prompt this uses PS exec to open a remote cmd session on the selected PC.

From this if a run a .bat file form a server share it comes back as access denied,
However the runas command e.g.

```
runas /Administrator cmd.exe /c "\\svr-sccm\ad$\!!! User cleanup batchfiles\Delete all user no input.bat"
```

Runs with no errors but doesn't seem to actually do anything  (the bat file calls delprof2 to clean user profiles off of the C drive and registry)

Any suggestions on how I would be able to run the bat file remotely on a PC when a Non-admin user is logged in (without remote controlling)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: delprof2 can be run against a remote computer, no bat file required: `delprof2 /c:computername /u /d:30`

Comment: I think this question should be on [sf] instead, both delprof and sccm are professional administration tools which are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I only put it here as its more for help with the code aspect

Comment: del prof's remote tool doesn't run within my organisation as it requires a remote registry service to be enabled on all machines it isn't probably for security reasons, if theres a way to use it without having to enable this service everywhere then that could be a solution, Thanks for the replies :)

Answer (score 0):

`Access Denied` most likely signals you, that the user, which runs the command, does not have access to the share, that you are trying to access.
If your command really spins up a commandline with `psexec`, it will run in `SYSTEM` context, i.e. the computer on which you run the script, must have access to the file share.